# Extract SVG file and embed content on Html as SVG tag

Tags: html, reactjs, svg, webpack-5

I'm trying to import the content of SVG files into HTML on final bundler, as SVG tag, using the Webpack 5 assets modules.

As the docs says, we can do:

```
  {  
    test: /\.svg/,  
    type: 'asset/source',  
  },
```

But for some reason it's being load as a string, instead of a tag, how can I fix it? (load as SVG tag, instead of a string).

In the JS file it looks like:

```
import menu from './icon/menu.svg';

<span>{menu}</span>
```

The final bundle it shows all the SVG content, but as a string, like that it won't render:

```
"<svg ... </svg>"
```

I want to do like this, so the SVG will be able to inherit the colors from parent tags.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need `svgr` for that. Better use `create-react-app` where this functionality is available out-of-the box rather then fight webpack

Comment: Thanks, just found out that the output as string it's intentional on Webpack, so we need something more too handle the JSX.

Comment: Yes, that "something more" is `svgr`: https://react-svgr.com/